# File is being used by another process while deleting the file

Tags: c#

I have function to create a pdf and then send it to through mail in attachments.

**The function to create pdf:**

```
public string CreatePdf()
        {

            try
            {
                using (document = new Document())
                {

                    if (File.Exists(filePath))
                    {
                        workStream.Dispose();
                        File.Delete(filePath);
                    }
                // LOGIC to Create PDF
                    return filePath;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                document.Close();
                document.Dispose();
                workStream.Close();
            }
        }
```

**To add to attachments:**

```
myMail.attachment = new Attachment(new CreatePdf());
```

When i create file for the first time it is created fine, but when i try to create pdf again i get the following error on `File.Delete(filePath)`

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

I saw other similar questions but couldn't figure out what needs to be closed exactly as i have closed everything.

Comment: Attachements should be disposed too. Otherwise they keep the attachment locked

Comment: Don't check File.Exists() like that. Just call File.Delete() and handle the exception. Also, that catch block is meaningless. You can just remove it, and leave the try/finally by themselves.

Comment: Joel thanks for the suggestion i made the change as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with the code you provided. I personally think that you are not closing or disposing something like the attachment. Why don't you try implementing your attachment with a using statement?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) and [Lynx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3554963/lynx) got it solved don't know whether it is the right way. `Attachments` class is `IDisposable` so i thought it will dispose the stream on its own. i just added `attachments.dispose()`.